java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/v5/manager/interfaces/SDKManagerCallback;
I am trying to import DJI MSDK in android studio. Here is my error. Could you help me please ? I am executing it on my mobile device with an USB-C cable and Samsung galaxy A23. The application just start then immediately close.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.msdksample, PID: 32766

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/v5/manager/interfaces/SDKManagerCallback;
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1232)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1565)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1502)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7553)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2400)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dji.v5.manager.interfaces.SDKManagerCallback" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.msdksample/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes19.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~-eWG4_HS4prD1yHXBA-p0w==/com.example.msdksample-bZzjvNjR3MT6lTz4ZIxDsQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~-eWG4_HS4prD1yHXBA-p0w==/com.example.msdksample-bZzjvNjR3MT6lTz4ZIxDsQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~-eWG4_HS4prD1yHXBA-p0w==/com.example.msdksample-bZzjvNjR3MT6lTz4ZIxDsQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76) 
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1232) 
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1565) 
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1502) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7553) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)  

I saw this:

If you have already called com.secneo.sdk.Helper.install at the start but still encounter the same crash, you can try switching SDKManager.getInstance().init() to run on the main thread.

on another forum but it didn't help.
